# Only last record is being written to the json File when I am trying to write every record in the same file

Tags: java, json, file, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I debugged and found out that the file is getting re-written after every iteration.

Also, if I don't close the file nothing is getting written to the file. I am using BufferedWriter - do we need to close the file explicitly or it takes care of that?

Here is my code :

```
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(myrecords);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(jsonObj);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("JsonFilenew.json"));
            writer.write(jsonObj.toString());
            String records = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("JsonFilenew.json")));
            JFlat flatMe = new JFlat(records);
       
            flatMe.json2Sheet().headerSeparator().getJsonAsSheet();
            file.close();
            flatMe.write2csv("new.csv");

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand it you have two problem with your code:

1. If you use FileWriter without a second parameter it will destroy the original file - if you want to append to the file try `new FileWriter("JsonFilenew.json",true)`
2. I think the code where you read the file and write it back as flat json should be outside the loop as this should only be done once.

More:
Your other problem is that just sticking a whole lot of json files together doesn't make legal json. You need to make it a legal json array (i.e opened with a '['; each element separated by a ',' and closed with a ']'

Comment: Thanks @Elemental,  Adding second parameter as true did append the file, but it is showing -- Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 883 path--- myRecords is having the proper json format, is there something wrong in the conversion to jsonArray which is causing this error

Comment: Added more to my answer